# Validates as a phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a string as a phone number (digits and certain special characters). I used a existing code snippet from here: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/597 which seems to be correct. But everytime `string.match(format)` returns `null`, which causes to show the error message.

```
var format = /^(\+\d)*\s*(\(\d{3}\)\s*)*\d{3}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}$/;
var string = jQuery(".validate_phone").val();
if (string.match(format) != true) {
  // some error message
}
```

I checked already, `string` is filled which the expected value.

The following values should match:
339-4248
339-42-48
339 42 48
339 4248
3394248
(095) 3394248
(095)3394248
+7 (095) 3394248
+7 (095)3394248
+7(095) 3394248
+7(095)3394248

Everything else should show the error message.

What is wrong with this code? Thanks in advance!

**Update: Here is a test case** http://labuschin.com/material/phone

Comment: what is an "expected value" sample?

Comment: Can you post some example numbers you do or don't want to match? Right off the bat I see that international numbers are not handled correctly.

Comment: Some examples what to match and what not would be helpful. The Regex is quite complex.

Comment: Added some positive examples.
Shouldn't `match` return a Boolean an not a `null`

Comment: The regex matches all those examples, so the problem is not with the regex (although it's ugly). Perhaps there is whitespace around the test string?

Comment: Nope, no whitespace in my tests. Here is a testcase http://labuschin.com/material/phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friend over at Facebook helped me out successfully:

```
var format = /(\+\d)*\s*(\(\d{3}\)\s*)*\d{3}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}/;  
var nr= prompt("Phone number", "");    
if (nr.match(format) == null) {
  alert ("incorrect");  
} else {  
  alert ("correct");  
}
```

Changed if-clause and and removed the ^ at the beginning and the $ at the end. Works here: http://labuschin.com/material/phone

Answer (score 0):

A valid regex for that would be: `(\+\d\s*)?(\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\s*)?\d{3}([- ]?\d{2}){2}`.

However, `match()` returns `null` on non-matches and an array of captured values on matches - it will never return `true`. You are probably more interested in `search()` which returns the match position or -1 if the regex didn't match. E.g.:

```
var format = /^(\+\d\s*)?(\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\s*)?\d{3}([- ]?\d{2}){2}$/;
var string = jQuery(".validate_phone").val();
if (string.search(format) == -1) {
  // some error message
}
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work in my testcase. Everything remains "incorrect"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... you should not use "string" as var name.

```
var format = /^(\+\d)*\s*(\(\d{3}\)\s*)*\d{3}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}$/;
var nr= prompt("Phone number", "");
if (!nr.match(format)) {
alert ("incorrect");
} else {
alert ("correct");
}
```

works for me.

Comment: i tried it here: http://labuschin.com/material/phone
unfortunately it doesn't work either :(

Comment: Your online version works for me (FF, Chrome, Safari, hell - even in IE).
Tested "+7(095)3394248" and somer other values...

However, I got an validation error as I tried to copy&paste a number because there was an additional whitespace at the end. Maybe you should check that..

If you just type in some numbers, make shure your string is long enough (7 chars min)